# Incorrect container height based on the image inside it

Tags: css

As you can see in the attached pic, the `.grid-item` div doesn't have the exact height of the content inside it (in my case the `<img>`), but it seems to add a few pixel on the bottom.

How can I tell the `.grid-item` div to use the exact height of the image inside it?

Ideally if it's possible I'd like to keep `absolute` and `relative` positioning of the divs like it is in the example below.

[image]

**HTML structure:**

```
<section>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="item-content">
      <div class="caption">
        <!-- .... -->
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/700x400/" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
}

body{
  font: 16px/1.5em sans-serif;
}

img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  position:relative;
}

section{
  max-width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

section .grid-item{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  padding:20px;
}

section .grid-item .item-content{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

section .grid-item .item-content .caption{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#333;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  z-index:2;
}
```

-

**FULL CODE:** 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrydZX?editors=1100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:block` to your `img` rule: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbLXxd?editors=1100

Images are by default inline allowing you to vertically align them in blocks of text.  The key disadvantages are that this then results in them also being affected by line height, font size, kerning, etc.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you for the additional explaination too!